# What is faster preparing a sql query to make the query minimalistic or doing a lot of likes?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with about 100.000 customers to search through, what would be better practice and fastest with my search form:

Would it be better to do

```
if(strlen($_POST['firstname']))
{
   $search .= "AND `firstname` like :firstname";
}
if(strlen($_POST['lastname']))
{
   $search .= "AND `lastname` like :lastname";
}
// and so on for about 16 possible fields
```

Or to do

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `customers`
                           WHERE `firstname` LIKE :firstname,
                           AND `lastname` LIKE :lastname,
                           -- AND so on for about 16 elements");
```

Comment: There is a difference, in the first block i'm minimizing the number of likes being executed by evaluating if it needs to be there, in normal cases just one of the field being searched upon but with the option by restricting search by using multiple fields, eg all the persons from city x, gender female borin in the 80's, in the other I always execute a like with % present even if that form field isn't filled in. What would be more efficient, always execute a like with % or filtering which likes to execute, because there is also processor overhead in filtering.

Comment: OK. I understand. Then you can't use one instead of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been using mysql for a long time, so I will give a general answer based on my sqlserver experience (forgive me if I'm off-topic)

I assume you have indexes on all your 16 columns (or at least the ones that will always have relevant values provided )

In SQL Server, I wouldn't go for the second option, because :

- `NULL LIKE '%'` is always false (in sqlserver your 2nd query wouldn't return any row featuring a null value)
- the optimizer would do something too general, based on the table statistics. This would lead to horrible performances when high priority clauses are just '%' ( note that, in sqlserver, you can have query hints telling to use some indexes for columns that will always have relevant values provided)

Only point I see in second case is less code to interpret (php side and mysqlside)
but I'm afraid it's not worth it.

Hope this will help a little, **and don't forget to sanitize your entries**

Comment: I think `NULL LIKE '%'` is always _NULL_ (but it won't return rows like you said).

Comment: @SalmanA I don't know, seems (NULL LIKE '%') IS NULL produces a syntax error. But you are totally right anyway, I should have written 'is never true' (as NOT (NULL LIKE '%') is never true either)

Answer (score 0):

These 2 code blocks are not equal.
If firstname weren't filled, a latter one will find nothing, while former one will search on lastname.

Asking "which is faster" while you're using LIKE makes no sense - it would be **always** slow, no matter which syntax you choose.

Comment: There is a difference, in the first block i'm minimizing the number of likes being executed by evaluating if it needs to be there, in normal cases just one of the field being searched upon but with the option by restricting search by using multiple fields, eg all the persons from city x, gender female borin in the 80's, in the other I always execute a like with % present even if that form field isn't filled in.

What would be more efficient, always execute a like with % or filtering which likes to execute, because there is also processor overhead in filtering.